# Capture GET and POST with Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to capture a GET and/or POST request as its being sent from the browser to the server?

I have a web app that does full page refreshes after requests are made, and some of the pages have long response times from the server due to long running queries on the database.

So after one of these requests are made, the view that it was made from stays visible while the browser is "waiting for a response from server".

I want to add something that can be applied globally that will capture whenever a request is made to the server, and then trigger a loading spinner to run. 
Something like:

```
​window.onclick = function (e) {
    if (e.isGETorPOST) {
        startLoadingSpinner();
    }
}​
```

**Update:** I am not using AJAX to GET and POST. The requests are coming from hrefs and forms.

Comment: No, but you can capture and act upon the actions that trigger them. such as anchor tag clicks and form submits.

Comment: Your question is tagged as Jquery although I strongly recommend the use of Ajax for this to work properly , you can still work on anchor `<a>` Triggers , `<form>` submits as mentionned above by @KevinB but i would truly advise you to use ajax to work with request and responses as they come and go to start the loading Spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MVC (the story is tagged MVC), an easy way to see the HTTP method of the current action, the following way is easy to do:

```
var httpMethod = "@ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod";
```

`Request.HttpMethod` returns a string with GET, POST, DELETE, etc.  This text is rendered during view rendering only; it won't change in an AJAX scenario, unless you update the variable.

Then you can do in JS:

```
if (httpMethod == "GET" || httpMethod == "POST") {
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: My response had 2 different solutions; since you are using ASP.NET MVC, would the other option possibly work?